# rSyslog and short hostname

Tags: rsyslog

I'm working with rsyslog through multiple hops. What I want is the following, I do not want the short hostname in the msg I only want the IP. So the server sending the msg I do not want it to add its short hostname to the message being sent I only want the IP of the server.

I'm using RHEL 5.5 with rsyslog 3.22.1.3

Any ideas?

Comment: Somewhat related is http://serverfault.com/questions/26430/fqdns-during-migration-from-syslogd-to-syslog-ng

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in **GLOBAL DIRECTIVES** of rsyslog

**$template LineTemplate,"%timereported% %fromhost-ip% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"**

Then add below line just after the log file name

**;LineTemplate**