# Syslog-ng how to get domain names instead of IP address

Tags: hostname, syslog, domain-name, syslog-ng

How can syslog-ng get the domain names instead of IP address that I received? I'm able to get those information but in IP address, I would like to get the DST/HOST to domain names instead of getting IP address.

http://imageshack.com/a/img33/685/4aui.png

Also I did enable `use_dns`, `use_fqdn` and `keep_hostname` but I'm still unable to get the domain name.

```
options {
    use_dns (yes);
    use_fqdn (yes);
    keep_hostname (yes);
};
```

Comment: Do reverse DNS records exist for the IP addresses you are receiving syslog data from?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff I'm receiving syslog data from DD-WRT router.

Comment: @JienWai Syslog-NG can't (or at least *shouldn't*) molest the input data - It should log exactly what your device sends it. If you want IP addresses write a script to post-process the log. The options you're setting are only for syslog-ng's internal functionality (when it records who it got the data from)...

Comment: Related http://serverfault.com/questions/26430/fqdns-during-migration-from-syslogd-to-syslog-ng

Answer (score 1):

If you have these options set (as you should), then it means that there is no reverse dns lookup available for the incoming IP. In this case, you will need to manually add the hosts to your /etc/hosts file and ensure that your nsswitch.conf file is set to use:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Comment: How am I going to setting? It look exactly the same what you state here. For an example if I get the host address is `123.456.789.123` how am I going to display it original domain name like `google.com`

Comment: You would add the following to your /etc/hosts file: 123.456.789.123 myhost.domain.com

Comment: Except insert the IP instead of domain name manually, is there anyway that can covert IP to domain name automatically? There is a huge IP with different domain, I can expect I know each of them.

Comment: @JienWai, yes, that is what DNS is for :)