# How do I find the actual domain for an IP addresses in my web log that uses a CDN?

Tags: reverse-dns, cdn

I'm trying to analyze our web access log to report on which organizations are accessing our website. But for many of the IP addresses in the log, the reverse DNS lookup resolves to CDN domain names managed by companies like Akamai.

For example, the address `184.86.101.211` resolves to `a184-86-101-211.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com` when I do a reverse DNS lookup. But if I ping `sec.gov`, I also get that IP address.

I want to report on the actual organization, in this case `sec.gov`, not on the Akamai CDN domain.

Is there a reliable way to trace back from the IP address to source domain? Will it work across CDNs or do I possibly need a different approach for each type of CDN?

Comment: No, as there can be any number of domains making use of that IP address.  It IS Akamai's IP.

Answer (score 1):

Akamai uses a custom HTTP Header True-Client-IP, you will need to extract those IPs to collect the rDNS entries for each, you can pipe the access logs to syslog and have syslog to the rDNS lookup.

Sources:

- https://community.akamai.com/videos/1232
- [Syslog-ng how to get domain names instead of IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/556166/syslog-ng-how-to-get-domain-names-instead-of-ip-address)